# How to pass a variable through channel in Jsch?

Tags: jsch

Here is my code partially:

```
Channel channel_1 = session.openChannel("exec");                                       
int t=5;  
((ChannelExec)channel_1).setCommand("echo value : $(t)>> test.sh");  
channel_1.connect();channel_1.disconnect();
```

I want the script "test.sh" in my remote machine written as "value : 5"

But the output I get is "value :  " in the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
String command = "echo value : " + t + " >> test.sh";
((ChannelExec)channel_1).setCommand(command);
```